# java httprequest fetch the content of page to wait until javascript is done executing

Tags: java, javascript, httprequest, html

I have a piece of Java code for getting the content of a webpage. The partial content of the webpage will be loaded/retrieved by a javascript once the page is loaded. That is, the page contains a javascript which will load the rest of the content. In Java, I want to wait until that partial content is loaded before start the rest of process. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Java is typically a server-side technology while JavaScript is a client-side technology.  So if you want Java to wait for something on the client, it can't, because typically Java's job is to send something static (e.g. HTML) to the client.  That being said, Java can render JavaScript code that will be run by the browser, and that JavaScript code can continue the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to request the rest of the content from the server once the javascript processing is done.